# i m little confused about error handling with pattern matching in rust

Tags: rust, error-handling, pattern-matching

currently i m learn rust. i m little confused about error handling with pattern matching. this is my code

```
fn read_username() -> Result<String, io::Error> {

    let files = File::open("hello.txt");

    let file1 = match files {
        Ok(f) => f,
        Err(e) => Err(e) // why this is not valid
    };

    let file2 = match files {
        Ok(f) => f,
        Err(e) => return Err(e) // why this is valid
    };

    ........

}
```

in file1, my code has an error. but in file2, my code is working fine. How can be like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Err(e)` is not a `File` so you can't store it in `file1`, but that's what your first example tries to do, the second example returns from the function instead of trying to store anything in `file2`.

Comment: White this is true, `file1` is never explicitly defined as a `File`.
The error only occurs because the compiler infers the type of `file1` to what the first branch of the match evaluates to, being `File`, so the first and the second branch do not match.

Comment: i thought return on file2 would return the value to file2, but what happens is that it will return an Error in the read_username function. Because read_username returns Result<String, Err> so the statement on file2 is valid. Thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

Think to take a unique handle to file, beside handle(s) or file(s) on return of function; i.e, you'll receive a type Result (with two possible values: our handle or an error). After this, your can develop your logic.

Take a look in this example:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    // Create a path to the desired file
    let path = Path::new("hello.txt");
    let display = path.display();

    // Open the path in read-only mode, returns `io::Result<File>`
    let mut file = match File::open(&path) {
        Err(why) => panic!("couldn't open {}: {}", display, why),
        Ok(file) => file,
    };

    // Read the file contents into a string, returns `io::Result<usize>`
    let mut s = String::new();
    match file.read_to_string(&mut s) {
        Err(why) => panic!("couldn't read {}: {}", display, why),
        Ok(_) => print!("{} contains:\n{}", display, s),
    }

    // `file` goes out of scope, and the "hello.txt" file gets closed
}
```

from the book: [Rust by example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std_misc/file/open.html?highlight=File#open)

Comment: This provides an alternative (using `panic!`), but doesn't seem to address the heart of the question: Why does the `let file1 = ...` version not work?

Comment: i thought return on file2 would return the value to file2, but what happens is that it will return an Error in the read_username function. Because read_username returns Result<String, Err> so the statement on file2 is valid. Thank you for your explanation